# Is there an easy way to be notified of a greenlit game showing up in the store?

Tags: steam

When I find an interesting game on Steam Greenlight, I always make sure to follow it. For some reason, I was under the impression that I would surely be notified in some manner when and if the projects I followed make it to the Steam store. Turns out I was quite wrong.

Seeing how its a shame for me to not notice when things I actually wanted to buy are available for buying, I was wondering if there is any way to receive such notifications in a manner that would be easy to notice (something akin to the emails I get when games on my wishlist go on sale comes to mind).

Comment: Workaround: Follow steam_games on Twitter, they mostly announce new releases there in a timely manner. I have a row in Tweetdeck just for Steam. https://twitter.com/steam_games

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no such way to be notified when a specific game gets Greenlit. However, games on Greenlight are often approved in batches, so you may want to check the lists that come with each announcement.

One more thing: once a game has been greenlit, it doesn't come out immediately. Of the 454 Greenlit games on Steam right now, less than half have actually come out, so it may be a while before the game you're interested in actually comes on sale.

You can check out all the games that have been greenlit [here](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/browse/?appid=765&p=1&section=items&browsesort=pending&browsefilter=pending).

Comment: While what you say is indeed true, I was asking specifically about notifications regarding a game making it to the Steam store (as opposed to just being greenlit). This question came to be by me noticing a (greenlit) game I was quite eager for show up on the store unannounced. I may just as well have not seen it there.